# javascript not returni true on form validation

Tags: javascript

```
function validation() {
  //alert("in the validation")
  var rty = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var stt = document.getElementById("stt").value;
  var t = document.getElementById("gst").value;
  var clnm = document.getElementById("clname").value;
  var errorstring = "";
  //alert("clnm" + clnm);
  if (clnm == "" || clnm == null) {
    errorstring += "Please enter Client Display Name\n";
  }

  var clbill = document.getElementById("clbillname").value;
  //alert("cbil" + clbill);
  if (clbill == "" || clbill == null) {
    errorstring += "Please enter Client Bill Name\n";

  }
  var cladd = document.getElementById("claddress").value;
  //alert("cadd" + cladd);
  if (cladd == "" || cladd == null) {
    errorstring += "Please enter Client Billing Address\n";

  }

  if (rty == "" || rty == null) {
    errorstring += "Please enter City\n";

  }
  //alert("reached near"+stt);
  if (stt.trim() == "ALL") {
    //  alert("reached inside");
    errorstring += "Please select a state\n";

  }
  //alert("reached here");
  var tt = document.getElementsByName("gstreg");
  if (tt[0].checked) {
    //alert("reached inside");
    if (t == null || t == "") {
      errorstring += "Please Enter GST TIN\n";

    }
  }

  alert("validation");
  if (errorstring != "") {
    alert(errorstring);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

This above code is not returning true when every thing is correct.
I am calling this function on the click of submit button but still i am not able to get the values saved as the form is not submitting

The javascript function is not returning true under any circumstances

Comment: post full code in a codepen and provide , i will help you. :)

Comment: @user your browser has debugging features. Go step by step through your code and you will see which condition isn't satisfied. It's even faster than posting a question on SO!

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: Check the web console for error messages like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure condition was inside function...

check whether your function closed properly

```
function validation() {
 your code...

 if (errorstring != "") { alert(errorstring); return false; } else { return true; }

}
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation, it's inside the function. But he's missing the `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: thats what i mentioned as put inside validation function... he didnt say about error message he got

Comment: But it wasn't outside the function.

Comment: it is already inside the function but still it return false and alert when errorstring has some otherwise it is not returning true